# Two properties of $f(x) = x \ln { (\frac{2}{\pi} \arctan{x}) } $ how do I prove these?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let's look at the function

$$f(x) = x  \ln {  (\frac{2}{\pi}  \arctan{x}) }  $$

This function seems to be strictly increasing after certain point $x=a$.

(1) What is this point $a$ after which it is strictly increasing?
I don't necessarily need to know this value $a$ but I am curious.

I saw the derivative is a sum of two terms, and both go to zero as $x$ goes to infinity. Seems one of them goes with positive, the other one with negative values.

But I don't quite see which term goes to $0$ faster.

(2) Also how do I prove that

$$f(x) \lt \frac{-2}{\pi} $$ for  $x \gt a$ ?

**I am sure of all this, it's been checked in WA, I just cannot prove it by hand.**

**NOTE 1:** I already used all these properties of $f(x)$ to find this limit

$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{2}{\pi}  \arctan{x})^x = \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{f(x)} = e^{-2/\pi}  $

but I cannot quite prove these properties so... my calculation of this limit is not very rigorous yet.

Why is it not rigorous? Because I need to make sure [the 2nd additional condition here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Limits_of_compositions_of_functions) holds true in order to use the composite limit theorem. And that condition will be proved if I have (2) proved.

Here is the WA link for the [limit of f(x)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20%28%20x%20*%20ln%28%20%28%202%2Fpi%20%29%20*%20%20arctan%28x%29%29%20%29%20when%20x%20goes%20to%20infinity)

**NOTE 2:** Please assume I don't know Taylor series yet... Here is the original problem (maybe I should have started my description from there).

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (\frac{2}{\pi}  \arctan{x})^x =\ ? $$

It is given in a real analysis book right after the chapter about the L'Hopital rules. Using the L'Hopital rules I proved that

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} {f(x)} = -2/\pi \ \ $$

But I cannot prove that $f(x)$ stays below $-2/\pi$ while approaching it... which I think makes me unable to apply the composite limit theorem in order to find $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{f(x)}$

Comment: In that Wikipedia article you link about composite limits, the conditionals are linked with an or, not an and, because you only need one condition to use the theorem, you have the first because the exponential function is continuous everywhere, so you don’t need the second

Comment: @Robo300 Yes, I knew it's an OR. Oh... it was so simple then... I don't need condition 2) at all, I already have that condition 1) holds true. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x \log \left(\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}(x)}{\pi }\right)\implies f'(x)=\frac{x}{\left(x^2+1\right) \tan ^{-1}(x)}+\log \left(\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}(x)}{\pi}\right)$$ which is impossible to solve analytically. So, a numerical method should be used.

Plotting $f'(x)$, you will notice that its zero is close to $x=1.5$. So, to make things simple, develop $f'(x)$ as a Taylor series around $x=\sqrt 3$. This would give
$$f'(x)=\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}}{4 \pi }-\log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{3
   \left(3 \sqrt{3}-2 \pi \right) \left(x-\sqrt{3}\right)}{16 \pi ^2}-\frac{3
   \left(-9 \sqrt{3}-9 \pi +4 \sqrt{3} \pi ^2\right) \left(x-\sqrt{3}\right)^2}{64
   \pi ^3}+O\left(\left(x-\sqrt{3}\right)^3\right)$$ SOlve the quadratic and select the closest root which, numerically, is $1.46814$ while the exact solution is $1.48545$.

This is not very good; so, use the expansion to $O\left(\left(x-\sqrt{3}\right)^2\right)$ which gives
$$x_0=\sqrt 3+\frac{4 \pi  \left(3 \sqrt{3}-4 \pi  \log \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)}{9
   \sqrt{3}-6 \pi }$$ Using Newton method, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 1.343134740 \\
 1 & 1.457092451 \\
 2 & 1.484172827 \\
 3 & 1.485448564 \\
 4 & 1.485451248
\end{array}
\right)$$ The second derivative test confirms that this is the minimum.

With regard to the limit when $x\to \infty$, use again Taylor expansion
$$\tan ^{-1}(x)=\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{3 x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$
$$\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}(x)}{\pi }=1-\frac{2}{\pi  x}+\frac{2}{3 \pi  x^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$
$$\log \left(\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}(x)}{\pi }\right)=-\frac{2}{\pi  x}-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$x\log \left(\frac{2 \tan ^{-1}(x)}{\pi }\right)=-\frac{2}{\pi  }-\frac{2}{\pi ^2 x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks... But please assume I don't know Taylor series yet. This problem is in a real analysis book and comes before Taylor series is introduced. This problem is given after the chapter about the L'Hopital rules. So I guess there must be some simpler way. Please see that **Note 2** which I added in my problem description above.